# How can I move file around in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, file-moving

I know some ways to rename files using neotree or `SPC f f` but they involve renaming them. 
Is there a way to graphically select them and move them around in some other directories?

Comment: Just for completeness, if you are visiting the file in a buffer then you can usually also just use rename buffer via SPC f R and enter the new path (incl. new name) of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Someone just told me on chatroom that I can use dired or ranger. I'm using ranger so I can : C-SPC (on the files I want to move) -> R -> and choose the directory I want to place it in by navigating in the helm buffer.

Comment: Note that if you only want to move one file, marking with C-SPC is not necessary.